# proxy server for playing media (mplayer), how does it work?

Tags: proxy, mplayer

I do not have access to a network environment with a proxy server for reaching internet to test with. Therefor, I would like to ask you this newbie question:

-is it enough to set the proxy server settings in the network settings for the machine, or do I also need set the proxy server in meplayer (I noticed VLC e.g. had settings for it)?

what I am worried about is that if I also need to set it in mplayer, I have seen forum posts that there is (or was?) a bug in mplayer that made it impossible to use a proxy server if the audiostream requires authentication (which is the case in my application).

Thanks in advance
/j

Answer (score 1):

Platform-independent media players (like VLC, Mplayer, ffmpeg) usually do not use the "system settings", which are basically Internet Explorer's settings.

You can easily test it at home, by installing a ready-made WAMP or LAMP package and enabling `mod_proxy` in Apache. **Only do this behind a firewall if you do this for the first time, or else you can end up with creating an open proxy-server for the whole world.**